# Show hidden button on Click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

An easy question but i cant seem to find any answer in the internet, please help.

```
<input hidden="true"   class="btnsubmit"  id="myaddslide2" onClick="UPCURSLIDE()"  type="button" value="UPDATE"> 
<script>
 function showbutton(){}
</script>
```

I want to show the hidden button when i click an elelemnt or call a function

Comment: 'i cant seem to find any answer in the internet'... :D

Comment: Simple as type in google *jquery show hidden input* :P

Answer (score 5):

Use [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
function showbutton() {
    //$('input:button:hidden').show();
    $("#myaddslide2").show(); //directly target id
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/yKqL7/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

you can do some thing like this

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "(some selector e.g button ID, Name etc)", function(){

     jQuery('element_id or what ever selector you are passing').prop("hidden",false);
    });
```

or something like this

```
 jQuery(document).on("click", "(some selector e.g button ID, Name etc)", function(){

         jQuery('element_id or what ever selector you are passing').show();
        });
```

Comment: Why not .hide() or .show() ?

Comment: well they can be used too, i will edit thx for pointing

Comment: Check my answer .show();

Comment: @Anton:very true mate, but question was quite broad

Comment: @mplungjan: Again i mention that question was too broad and i gave answer with in almost same perspective he quoted `I want to show the hidden button when i click an element or call a function`

Comment: Ok hidden=true does seem to be a valid prop at least in mobile safari

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `show()` method

```
function showbutton(){
   $('#myaddslide2').show();
}
```

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1):

```
function showbutton() {

    $("#myaddslide2").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function showbutton(){
   $('#myaddslide2').fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var showbutton = function() {
    $("#myaddslide2").prop("hidden",false);
}
```

Anyways, i would do it via css and `display:none` ... just my preference.

Answer (score 1):

when you click on any element say,

```
showbutton(){$(#myaddslide2).show();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("#myaddslide2").prop("hidden",false);
```

or

```
$("#myaddslide2").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code will work

```
function showbutton(){

   $('#myaddslide2').show();

}
```